# Read a file into variable preserving spaces and newlines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

As the question implies I am intending to store the input through a bash script in raw format using a single variable.

Basically when the input prompt occurs, I would be pasting some bunch of lines and then writing that stored variable to a text file. After a bit of search I did came across readarray but it is not storing the input/paste in its original paste state

Just for the purpose of simplicity lets say the input/paste I am intending to store in the variable is as follows:

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
```

Expected script

```
#!/bin/bash
#the part i need help with ( Store the multiple line input/paste in raw format in a variable called let say test ) 
....
echo "$test" > test.txt
cat test.txt
```

This should print that 1..5 exactly in the format I have pasted during input prompt in console / also shown above

Edit - It might be possible someone is curious what is my actual use case, so I am giving an example what my paste actually is in real use case. I used 1..5 example in question only for simplicity.

```
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXizsW4-32313922.mp4
  out=Lecture 01- AS 1 Theory.mp4
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXX6XFPB-32313922.mp4
  out=Lecture 02- AS 1 Question.mp4
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXIeQNM-32313922.mp4
  out=Lecture 03- AS 2 Theory.mp4
```

I would be pasting text in such format only

```
https://link
  out=Some-Name.mp4 ( 2 spaces before word out )
```

Although there are 300,400 such pairs of lines that I would be pasting (if that matters).

Comment: define: "readarray but it doesn't suit my needs"

Comment: It is not storing my paste in variable in a raw format

Comment: What do you mean by "raw format"? Can you provide an example of an input and the expected output, in an unambiguous form (perhaps a hex dump or a `$'C-style string\n'` if you need to include control codes or other nonprintable characters)?

Comment: By raw format , i mean it should store exactly what i paste during the input prompt . It should preserve all indentation and spaces

Comment: @tripleee there you go , i have also added my real use case scenario in question.  I hope now everything is clear

Comment: *raw* is really a poor word choice here, I thought you wanted to keep NUL bytes too, which is impossible.

Comment: You are probably writing the file incorrectly. I am unable to repro any corruption; demo at https://ideone.com/RmERB6

Comment: i apologize to everyone for my incorrect terminology that might have caused any confusion . @tripleee , i saw your solution and realized my mistake thanks for correction . If you can answer that , it would give viewers an alternative answer  ( we have got one good answers using while loop , other 2 are invalid )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is apparently with how you write the variable. If you use an array, you need to quote it correctly when you write it.

```sh
readarray -d $'\n' test
printf '%s\n' "${test[@]}"
```

Perhaps see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 6):

If this isn't all you need then post a new question:

```
$ foo=$(< file)
$ printf '%s\n' "$foo"
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
```

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
$ cat test.txt
 1
  2
   3
    4
     5
```

Several ways:

First, you can use process substitution to read the file contents into a single variable:

```
$ txt="$(cat test.txt)"
$ echo "$txt"
 1
  2
   3
    4
     5
```

Or, you can loop over the contents of the file line-by-line and preserve the formatting:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done <test.txt
' 1'
'  2'
'   3'
'    4'
'     5'
```

(Remove the `'` in `printf "'%s'\n"` to remove those from the output)

---

Edit

Your edit makes your question less clear, but it seems that you are dealing with a large number (300,400 you state) of line pairs.

If so, your best bet is to use `awk` to deal with line pairs:

```
$ echo "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXizsW4-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 01- AS 1 Theory.mp4
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXX6XFPB-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 02- AS 1 Question.mp4
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXIeQNM-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 03- AS 2 Theory.mp4"  | awk '!(NR%2){sub(/mp4/,"MP4 EVEN LINE")}1' 
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXizsW4-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 01- AS 1 Theory.MP4 EVEN LINE
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXX6XFPB-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 02- AS 1 Question.MP4 EVEN LINE
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/XXXIeQNM-32313922.mp4
    out=Lecture 03- AS 2 Theory.MP4 EVEN LINE
```

(Remove the `!` from `!(NR%2)` to deal with the odd pairs.)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -r -d $'\004' test
echo "$test" > /tmp/test.txt
```

Press CTRL-D after you've pasted the input and check the file `/tmp/test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat 12345
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
$ cat 12.sh
#!/bin/bash

readarray -d '\n' lines

echo "$lines" > 12345.tmp
echo "$lines"
$ cat 12345 | ./12.sh
1
 2
  3
   4
    5

$ cat 12345.tmp
1
 2
  3
   4
    5

$
```

Comment: This is not correct; `$lines` is not the array, just its first element.

Comment: I fail to see the difference between my post, and your (@tripleee). Both  read the data in the same way, so in your case the data is also (only) in the first element?

Comment: Ok, but i do not have a '$' in `readarray -d '\n' lines`. Demo:   https://ideone.com/0ODbmb

Comment: Yeah, that's a separate bug, as pointed out by Ed Morton. Demo: https://ideone.com/TGDqvg

Comment: On 'normal' input () the complete file gets read into one variable (the first element of an array). The separate bug is a completely different story. Finally, yes maybe i should have typed `echo ${lines[@]}` for the output, but since i only read 1 element ....

Comment: Then why do you use an array at all? `read -r -d 'no such separator no sirree' lines` would be less confusing. (And still you need to quote the variable you `echo`.) Demo: https://ideone.com/Zo2fsZ

Comment: See first comment on the question, which is a reaction on the question. Unfortunately the  text in the question is changed since i posted that reaction.

Comment: Still "I want an array but none of the useful features of an array" is a puzzling interpretation.